# Invalid Url on Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

On First Load, let's say http://localhost:6969/app/main/login
but when I try to change the browser url http://localhost:6969/app/main/register, it doesn't
redirect to http://localhost:6969/app/main/register, it simply reloads and
loads the http://localhost:6969/app/main/login.
I am not sure where the issue is happening.

Here is my code:

```
`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: PageLayoutComponent,
    data: { title: 'SMS' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'main',
        loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        loadChildren: () => import('./error/error.module').then(m => m.ErrorModule)
      }
    ]
  }
]

const handledRoutes: Routes = [];
routes.forEach((route) => {
  const handledRoute = {
    path: route.path.toLowerCase(),
    component: route.component,
    canActivate: route.canActivate,
    data: route.data,
    redirectTo: route.redirectTo,
    pathMatch: route.pathMatch
  };
  handledRoutes.push(handledRoute);
  handledRoutes.push(route);
});`
```

I am expecting that the URL should be redirect to the register page.